# How to draw a line chart from datetime only data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There is csv with only the date and time of access as below

```
2018-09-01 13:23:14 UTC
2018-09-01 13:23:29 UTC
2018-09-01 13:23:32 UTC
2018-09-01 13:23:34 UTC
...
2018-10-21 20:04:16 UTC
2018-10-21 20:04:18 UTC
2018-10-21 20:04:20 UTC
2018-10-21 20:04:21 UTC
2018-10-21 20:04:24 UTC
2018-10-21 20:04:26 UTC
2018-10-21 20:04:27 UTC
```

I would like to confirm in which time zone the access is heavy, with a line chart in minutes.
I tried it like this, but it will not work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import csv

with open('./access.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    i = 0
    header = next(f)
    time = []
    count = []
    for row in f:
        time.append(row)
        count.append(1)

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'time': pd.to_datetime(time),
        'count': count
    })
    df = df.set_index('time')

    plt.show()
```

How can it work?

Comment: This is not a full answer, but rather an advice: read the csv file with `df = pd.read_csv('./access.csv')`, you don't need to parse it manually. Anyways if you post the csv file in actual csv format, with commas and stuff, we can give you a solution. You will need to group by minutes and use a bar plot with time as the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the csv as a pandas Series like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./access.csv')
```

From there you can turn the values to datetime then plot the minute values as a line plot with matplotlib:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df)
min_counts = df.dt.minute.value_counts()
plt.plot(min_counts.index, min_counts)
plt.show()
```